# Py-cordを使って、スラッシュコマンドが見えるユーザを制限したい

Tags: python, discord

PythonでDiscordのBot作成を行っています。

ユーザがDiscord上で「/」を入力したときに、使えるコマンド一覧が出てきます(スラッシュコマンド)。特定のコマンドを管理者のみ・特定のロールのみ見えるようにするにはどういった方法がありますか？実行されてからユーザをチェックするのではなく、そもそもコマンド一覧に見えないようにしたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

コード例

```py
import discord, os

bot = discord.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents, auto_sync_commands=True)

@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=GUILD_IDS, name="help")
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("help command", ephemeral=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run(os.environ.get('DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN'))
```

環境

- Python 3.8.10
- [py-cord](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord) 2.4.1